# How can I call helper function in external PHP file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

External PHP file was in Web-root. I created one own helper class. Now I want to call that function from PHP file

**Code:**

```
$ReviewCount=$this->Search->getReviewsCount(); 
echo $ReviewCount
```

It was working view file 
but
its showing error in External PHP file:
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: Why using a php file in webroot?. $this represent an object. If you're php file is not an object the error is normal.

Comment: Actually .i want refresh the layout content Div with view-file without  refresh whole page . i am tried and searched lots thing but not worked .so i created external php file in webroot with same code of view .then i am loaded content div with that external php file by using Jquery after success ajax call .every thing is ok but when trying to use cakephp functionalities like session ,hellpers in that external php file.was not working.can u help me..?